# Unkown service on the windows startup list

Tags: boot, virus, services

I have discovered an unkown process/application name on my windows 10 startup list i cannot seem to link to any known installed software.

I cannot locate it, nor find anything about it online.
It is name ''Qorigjsr'' and was turned on at start up. I have disabled it just to be sure but would like to know if anyone knows what this links to?

I have an active AV and have ran ccleaner, adw cleaner and Anti-Malwarebytes.

Thanks!

Comment: This is the Startup tab list in Task Manager? When you click on Open file location are there any files?  Do you see the same entry in Autoruns? https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx

Answer (score 1):

that one doesn't personally tell me anything but you did good by disabling it. To be safe, you could boot in safe mode and run your AV and other tools you got. I would personally go with a bootable rescue disk with your prefered AV but I'm paranoid like that. some viruses will completely ignore your AV sometimes and sometimes come back even if you think they are gone.

Also, I run superantispyware. i admit it looks like a scam software but its not. look around in reviews and you'll know. give it a try.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, i will give superantispyware a go! I remember using that a couple of years ago.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes malware developers will write their programs so that a random name is used in file and process names so that it will be more difficult for users to identify the malware. Like FlashofBlue, [I've used SUPERAntispyware](http://support.moonpoint.com/security/scans/20161217/SUPERAntiSpyware/) to rid systems of a lot of malware and would recommend it. Other programs you can use for free to check your system include the following:

1. [Ad-Aware Free Antivirus+](http://www.lavasoft.com/products/ad_aware_free.php)
2. [Malwarebytes Free](https://www.malwarebytes.com/mwb-download/)
3. [Sophos Virus Removal Tool](https://www.sophos.com/en-us/products/free-tools/virus-removal-tool.aspx)
4. [SUPERAntispyware](http://www.superantispyware.com/)
5. [Spybot - Search & Destroy](https://www.safer-networking.org/)

For hard to identify and isolate malware, I've had to use multiple anti-malware programs at times. Sometimes one particular company or organization has already encountered it and has updated their virus/spyware definitions to detect it while others have not yet encountered it. So for malware x, product A, B, and C may miss it, but product D may find it while for malware y, A, C, and D may not identify it, but B does.

Other tools you can use to scan a system for malware include [Rootkit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rootkit) detectors:

1. [GMER](http://www.gmer.net/)
2. [Kaspersky TDSSKiller](http://usa.kaspersky.com/downloads/TDSSKiller)
3. [Malwarebytes Anti-Rootkit](https://www.malwarebytes.org/antirootkit/)

I also often boot an infected system from a [Live CD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_CD), so that the operating system normally used to boot the system is not running at the time of the scan. Many antivirus vendors provide a free Live CD you can use for such purposes. Some that I've used include the following:

1. [Avira Rescue System](http://www.avira.com/en/download/product/avira-rescue-system)
2. [AVG Rescue CD](http://support.moonpoint.com/security/antivirus/avg/rescue-cd/version120/)
3. [BitDefender Rescue CD](http://support.moonpoint.com/security/antivirus/bitdefender/rescuecd/apt-get.php)
4. [F-Secure Rescue CD](http://support.moonpoint.com/security/antivirus/f-secure/rescue_cd_3-16.php)
5. [Kaspersky Rescue Disk](http://support.kaspersky.com/us/viruses/rescuedisk)

If you can identify the file associated with the process, you can upload it to Google's [VirusTotal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VirusTotal) website and have it checked with multiple antivirus programs. [Jotti's malware scan](https://virusscan.jotti.org/) provides a similar service.